# Why is `Appointment.Recurrence.Until` (unexpectedly) off by one after saving and loading it?

Tags: calendar, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm saving an appointment to an `AppointmentCalendar` using `AppointmentCalendar.SaveAppointmentAsync(...)`. This appointment is the **master** of a **series** containing `Recurrence` information.

Right after saving the appointment I retrieve the very same appointment again by calling `GetAppointmentAsync` on the same calendar using the appointment's `LocalId`.

Here is the unexpected behavior: there is a difference in the loaded appointment: the `Recurrence.Until` date is **off by one**.
Why is this?

Here are the involved appointments serialized as JSON :

The `Appointment` I save:

```
{ 
    "Location": "", 
    "AllDay": false, 
    "Organizer": null, 
    "Duration": "00:45:00", 
    "Details": "", 
    "BusyStatus": 0, 
    "Recurrence": { 
        "Unit": 1, 
        "Occurrences": 260, 
        "Month": 1, 
        "Interval": 1, 
        "DaysOfWeek": 62, 
        "Day": 1, 
        "WeekOfMonth": 0, 
        "Until": "2016-12-31T01:00:00+01:00",
        "TimeZone": "Europe/Budapest", 
        "RecurrenceType": 0, 
        "CalendarIdentifier": "" 
    }, 
    "Subject": "test", 
    "Uri": null, 
    "StartTime": "2016-01-04T11:30:00+01:00", 
    "Sensitivity": 0, 
    "Reminder": null, 
    "Invitees": {}, 
    "AllowNewTimeProposal": true, 
    "UserResponse": 0, 
    "RoamingId": "c,b,fd", 
    "ReplyTime": null, 
    "IsResponseRequested": true, 
    "IsOrganizedByUser": false, 
    "IsCanceledMeeting": false, 
    "OnlineMeetingLink": "", 
    "HasInvitees": false, 
    "CalendarId": "b,37,355", 
    "LocalId": "c,37,20a3", 
    "OriginalStartTime": null, 
    "RemoteChangeNumber": 0, 
    "DetailsKind": 0, 
    "ChangeNumber": 39537577 
}
```

And here is this very same `Appointment` after retrieving it by calling `GetAppointmentAsync`:

```
{ 
    "Location": "", 
    "AllDay": false, 
    "Organizer": null, 
    "Duration": "00:45:00", 
    "Details": "", 
    "BusyStatus": 0, 
    "Recurrence": { 
        "Unit": 1, 
        "Occurrences": 260, 
        "Month": 1, 
        "Interval": 1, 
        "DaysOfWeek": 62, 
        "Day": 1, 
        "WeekOfMonth": 0, 
        "Until": "2016-12-30T01:00:00+01:00",
        "TimeZone": "Europe/Budapest", 
        "RecurrenceType": 0, 
        "CalendarIdentifier": "GregorianCalendar" 
    }, 
    "Subject": "test", 
    "Uri": null, 
    "StartTime": "2016-01-04T11:30:00+01:00", 
    "Sensitivity": 0, 
    "Reminder": null, 
    "Invitees": {}, 
    "AllowNewTimeProposal": true, 
    "UserResponse": 0, 
    "RoamingId": "c,b,fd", 
    "ReplyTime": null, 
    "IsResponseRequested": true, 
    "IsOrganizedByUser": false, 
    "IsCanceledMeeting": false, 
    "OnlineMeetingLink": "", 
    "HasInvitees": false, 
    "CalendarId": "b,37,355", 
    "LocalId": "c,37,20a3", 
    "OriginalStartTime": null, 
    "RemoteChangeNumber": 0, 
    "DetailsKind": 0, 
    "ChangeNumber": 39537577 
}
```

Diffing these JSONs you get two differences in the `Recurrence` part:

`CalendarIdentifier` is empty in the original appointment to save (because the setter is private). But more important: `Recurrence.Until` differs!

`Recurrence.Until` for appointment to save: "2016-12-31T01:00:00+01:00"

`Recurrence.Until` for appointment after loading: "2016-12-30T01:00:00+01:00"

One day is missing.

Why is this? Is there anything else I need to do when saving the appointment? Or worse: Is it just an edge case with my calendars and appointments, maybe even connected to the current date?

(SDK Version 10.0.14393.0, Win 10 Anniversary)

Answer (score 1):

I did many testing on my side. In my testing if I set the time of the until day before 8:00 AM, the result of the `recurrence.until`will off by one day as you showed above, setting other time will got the right day but no matter what time you actually set the result you got will be 8:00 AM. Details please see the following test result.

[image]

It seems to relative to the timezone(my timezone is UTC+8:00). The simple workaround is when you setting the `until`, just set the date to it like follows: `recurrence.Until = UntilDatePicker.Date;`, don't set the specific time to the `until`. Actually we don't need the specific time when setting the `until` even we set it manually in calendar app.

[image]

I also upload a demo you can download for further testing.

Comment: Dear @Sunteen, thanks for looking into this! Unfortunately I can't use any UI to create appointments as I'm backing up appointments internally. And this has to be a 1:1 backup, so I need to duplicate `Appointment` objects with all its properties. From your answer I see that I could start experimenting with time zones of the appointments to get where I want. But doesn't the whole behaviour look like a bug or at least non-intuitive behavior to you?